# como podría trabajar con diferentes ficheros CS? en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una ventana en C# con windowsForm y con un TabControl que tiene muchas pestañas y cada pestaña tiene varios controles dentro, por lo que la  cantidad de metodos y eventos notable, por lo que trabajar en ese fichero.cs se está haciendo un poco complicado, sabría alguien decirme si se puede dividir en varios ficheros cs, uno por tabpor ejemplo y como hacerlo?

gracias

Answer (score 0):

ya encontré la solución, por si a alguien le sirve la publico aquí

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

Un saludo